# Adding tinyMCE to dynamically added textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, dhtml

I have some javascript that opens a lightbox which contains dynamically created HTML, including some textareas. I then do...

```
tinyMCE.init({mode: "none", theme: "simple"});
tinymce.execCommand("mceAddControl", true, id);
```

...where *id* is the id of one textarea in particular. I know the id is correct, because that textarea disappears (it suddenly has *display:none* as an inline style?), but if I remove that inline style, the textarea appears again unchanged, but with no tinymce editor attached. Why is that inline style being applied, and why doesn't it have an attached editor?

---

### Edit for Thariama

Edit 2 - code contained a bug, still doesn't work after fix though...

Ok here is an example that shows the issue.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="tiny_mce.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="list">
        </ul>    
    </body>

    <template id="thingyTemplate">
        <li>
            <label>Email rich text body:</label>
            <textarea rows="8" cols="50" path="bodyRichText" class="wysiwyg"></textarea>
        </li>
    </template>

    <script>

        var newTemplate = $("#thingyTemplate > *").clone();
        $(newTemplate).find("textarea").attr("id", "myTextArea");
        $("#list").append(newTemplate);

        tinyMCE.init({ mode: "none", theme: "simple" });
        tinymce.execCommand("mceAddControl", false, "myTextArea");

    </script>
</html>
```

When the page loads, you can see the *template* element but the clone()'d copy in the list disappears. If you remove the *mceAddControl* line however the template and its clone are visible.

Comment: is that specific textarea hidden when you call mceAddControl?

Comment: It was, but even if I change it so that the element is visible before I call mceAddControl, it suddenly disappears when the call is made!

Comment: this is wierd and should not happen, can you show me a live example?

Answer (score 8):

I tried this:

```
tinymce.remove();
    tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea',
        setup: function (editor) {
            editor.on('change', function () {
                editor.save();
            });
        },
        height: 100,
        width: 350,
        menubar: false,
        plugins: [
          'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor',
          'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
          'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste code',
          'textcolor'
        ],
        toolbar: 'undo redo | insert | styleselectfontselect fontsizeselect | forecolor backcolor | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
        content_css: '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
    });
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to delay that call to "document-ready"? Maybe your DOM isn't fast enough or in your code you are having the same IDs ;)

```
    $(function(){
            tinyMCE.init({ mode: "none", theme: "simple" });
            tinymce.execCommand("mceAddControl", false, "myTextArea");
    });
```

Comment: Do you know what's the replacement for `mode: "none"` in v4 of TinyMCE? This option is no longer available.

Comment: It seems, that they decided to give you more control about the target: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:selector, so you directly specify where to spawn the editor. Does this help you?